# Bug in Transformed Multi-Normal distribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Why is the Mathematica resulting in the weird output whenever the number of variables in the transformed distribution becomes greater than the number of variables in the original multivariate Normaldistribution?

This is correct:

```
TransformedDistribution[{y1 + y2, y1 + y3, y1 + y4, 
  y2 + y3}, {y1, y2, y3, y4} \[Distributed] 
  MultinormalDistribution[{\[Mu]1, \[Mu]2, \[Mu]3, \[Mu]4}, 
   IdentityMatrix[4]]]
```

results in correct output

```
MultinormalDistribution[{\[Mu]1 + \[Mu]2, \[Mu]1 + \[Mu]3, \[Mu]1 + \
\[Mu]4, \[Mu]2 + \[Mu]3}, {{2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 
   0}, {1, 1, 0, 2}}]
```

But this

```
TransformedDistribution[{y1 + y2, y1 + y3, y1 + y4, y2 + y3, y1 + y2 + y3 + y4}, {y1, y2, y3, y4} \[Distributed]    MultinormalDistribution[{\[Mu]1, \[Mu]2, \[Mu]3, \[Mu]4},     IdentityMatrix[4]]]
```

results in weird output

```
TransformedDistribution[{\[FormalX]1 + \[FormalX]2, \[FormalX]1 + \
\[FormalX]3, \[FormalX]1 + \[FormalX]4, \[FormalX]2 + \[FormalX]3, \
\[FormalX]1 + \[FormalX]2 + \[FormalX]3 + \[FormalX]4}, {\[FormalX]1, \
\[FormalX]2, \[FormalX]3, \[FormalX]4} \[Distributed] 
  MultinormalDistribution[{\[Mu]1, \[Mu]2, \[Mu]3, \[Mu]4}, {{1, 0, 0,
      0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}]]
```

Is this some Mathematica bug or bug in my understanding?

thanks

Comment: The second distribution is correct. Mathematica doesn't know a shorter or simpler representation of the distribution so it is represented as the input distribution with formal variables. If that distribution is called `dist` then you can evaluate `Mean[dist]` or `StandardDeviation[dist]` as you would with any distribution..

Comment: `PDF[TransformedDistribution[{y1+y2,y1+y3,y1+y4,y2+y3,y1+y2+y3+y4},{y1,y2,y3,y4}\[Distributed]MultinormalDistribution[{\[Mu]1,\[Mu]2,\[Mu]3,\[Mu]4},IdentityMatrix[4]]],{t1,t2,t3,t4,t5}]` fails in 13 on Windows 10. Every command has its limitations.

Answer (score 8):

In short, your examples are of multivariate normals with covariance matrices that are not positive definite.  (They are symmetric just not symmetric positive definite.)

As @BobHanlon mentions, `Mean[dist]` and `StandardDeviation[dist]` work fine.

Another command that works fine is `Covariance`:

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[{y1 + y2, y1 + y3, y1 + y4, y2 + y3, y1 + y2 + y3 + y4}, 
  {y1, y2, y3, y4} \[Distributed] MultinormalDistribution[{μ1, μ2, μ3, μ4}, IdentityMatrix[4]]]

(cov = Covariance[dist]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Covariance matrix]

But `cov` is singular:

```
Det[cov]
(* 0 *)
```

So my guess is that is probably related to the issue you're finding.

Suppose we try to construct the multivariate normal from knowing that covariance matrix:

```
MultinormalDistribution[cov]
```

This fails with the error message

[image: Error message]

Now suppose we construct a multivariate normal distribution from that covariance matrix (which doesn't know that it was constructed from 4 independent normals) and specify the mean:

```
dist2 = MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, cov]
```

No error messages are given.  But try `Mean`:

```
dist2 = MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, cov];
Mean[dist2]
```

[image: Error message about not having a symmetric positive definite matrix]

So I think it's all about not having a symmetric positive definite matrix in your examples.